# PageMap in wicket 6.x or 7.x

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-6, wicket-1.6, wicket-7

I am trying to convert below code into wicket 6.x, But I am unable to find some required methods, does anybody have any solution for this?

```
  PopupSettings popupSettings = new PopupSettings(PageMap.forName("popuppagemap"), PopupSettings.SCROLLBARS).setHeight(500).setWidth(700);
```

Comment: You don't  need `pageMap` just pass the string `popuppagemap`

Comment: You mean to say like this?
PopupSettings popupSettings= new PopupSettings("popuppagemap", PopupSettings.SCROLLBARS).setHeight(500).setWidth(700);

Thank you very much, here am not getting any option to accept your answer rather than favorite

Comment: I will add as a answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need a PageMap You can send only string :

```
PopupSettings popupSettings = new PopupSettings("popuppagemap", PopupSettings.SCROLLBARS).setHeight(500).setWidth(700);
```

To know more [check this link](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/PopupSettings.java)